# Accidently overwrote /boot folder files

Tags: 14.04, boot

I was trying to install a chronOS kernel. But instead of copying vmlinuz-3.19.0-25-chronos, System.map-3.0.24-chronos, config-3.0.24-chronos i overwrote vmlinuz-3.19.0-25-generic, System.map-3.0.24-generic, config-3.0.24-generic. I have not rebooted yet. Can someone tell me how can i get these files back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic
```

In general, you can find out what package owns a file with `dpkg -S /path/to/file` and reinstall if needed.